# Test temporary file existence in JUNIT , mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a function, which generates a CSV file using CSV printer, emails and then deletes the file by calling another private function. The private function which sends the email is :

```
private void sendEmail(File fileToSend) {
      List<String> emailTo = xyz@gmail.com
      String emailFrom = abc@gmail.com
      String host = host //cannot write the proper host name
      
      try
      {
          mailUtil.sendMailWithAttachment(emailFrom, emailTo, host)
          logger.debug("Email successfully sent");
      } catch (Exception e) {
          logger.error("Exception when sending mail ", e);
      }
      finally {
          deleteFile(fileToSend);
      }
  }
```

```
private File saveInCsv(List<List <String> > valuesToStore) {
        String fileName = "hello.csv";
        File deletedIncidentCsv = new File(fileName);

        try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(deletedIncidentCsv));

             CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(bufferedWriter, CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader(headers).withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.ALL));
        )
        {
            for (List<String> strings : valuesToStore) {

                csvPrinter.printRecord(strings);
            }
            csvPrinter.flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Error in writing to CSV file ", e);
        }
        return deletedIncidentCsv;
    }
```

both these private functions are being called by public function , which I am testing:

```
public generateEmailFile(){
        //does some work to retrieve dataToWriteInCSV
        File csvFileGenerated = saveInCsv(dataToWriteInCsv);
                sendEmail(csvFileGenerated);
}
```

In my unit test I want to check the contents of the file before its deleted. Is there anyway of doing it.

Comment: Why can't you read the file before it's deleted?

Comment: Why do you need to test the content of the file? It's not created in any code you've shown, i.e., doesn't seem to be relevant to the code you want to test.

Comment: @accessviolation Apologies for half code, I have update the code

Comment: @Jeremy I have updated code which will give you clarity, send EMail is private function

Comment: `sendEmail` doesn't use the file, other than to delete it. But I would extract the csv file generation into a separate class, and test that in a different test.